# How can I use padding to move an image inside a picturebox in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to move an image inside a picturebox with the mouse by changing the padding of the picturebox. I am able to move the image, but it [moves too much](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjpUW.jpg). This is what I got so far:

```
private bool mouseDown;
private Point lastLocation;

private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        mouseDown = true;
        lastLocation = e.Location;
    }
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (mouseDown == true)
    {
        int dx = e.X - lastLocation.X;
        int dy = e.Y - lastLocation.Y;
        pictureBox1.Padding = new Padding(pictureBox1.Padding.Left + dx,
                                     pictureBox1.Padding.Top + dy, 0, 0);
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mouseDown = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help, I found a solution:

Under MouseMove, I replaced

```
pictureBox1.Padding = new Padding(pictureBox1.Padding.Left + dx,
                                 pictureBox1.Padding.Top + dy, 0, 0);
```

with

```
pictureBox1.Padding = new Padding(Padding.Left + dx, Padding.Top + dy, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you're adding more padding each time by referring to the current padding when adding more padding:

```
   pictureBox1.Padding = new Padding(pictureBox1.Padding.Left + dx,
                                 pictureBox1.Padding.Top + dy, 0, 0);
```

Try instead:

```
   pictureBox1.Padding = new Padding(dx, dy, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you. However, now it moves correctly the first time I move it, but the second time the image jumps back to it's previous position before being moved.